# Select Distinct/Unique Rows from a Huge Table in SQL Server Without Timeout Errors

Tags: sql-server, sql, timeout

I have a table in SQL Server with around 400,000 rows. Unfortunately, this table has many duplicate rows, as there isn't a primary key. I'm using `SELECT DISTINCT` to get all unique rows, but as there's so many of them, I keep getting timeout errors. What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow?

Comment: You wont get a proper answer unless you post your table definition (script it out in SSMS with right-click script table as... CREATE), any indexes defined against the table and your query.  Best guess if that you should create a clustered index on the column your distinct is on.

Comment: @Nick I'll do that, but, fyi, my distinct is on all the columns, not just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Improove timeout - raise the value. Or throw in more power. Technically 400.000 rows is not a lot, so it would go very fast for a decent server. Otherwise - if you have IO problems because your "server" has only one (pair of) hard discs.... then your IO Will kill you.

Basically, DISTINCT triggers a temporary result creation in the tempdb - so it is tempdb heavy.

But at the end, I would increase timeout, especially if this is a one time operation only.

Btw., to put that into perspective - where is the HUGH table you talk about? 400.000 is trivial in size.

Comment: How do I raise the timeout value? Thanks for your answer!

About the 400,000 = huge thing, it feels huge for me, but it's subjective.

Comment: Actually it is not subjective - pretty much standard anything below one million is trivial (not even small). 1.000.000 records where small 10 yars ago (Foxpro) ;) TImeout - check command, connection object. CHeck connection string parameters.

Comment: For the timeout thing, I'm running the query directly from SQL Server Management Server. Is there a way to set it there?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for speeding this up is to add an index on the field that you need to select against.  Using a select statement where the database engine has to filter results without an index essentially requires the server to walk through every row in the table.

Comment: Will not help. A distinct NOT On only the key will trigger a table scan anyway, index or not.

Comment: True, I should clarify that to be effective, the index would have to be on all fields which are the target of the DISTINCT.  Re-reading the question though I'm curious what the structure of this table looks like and the exact query that's being run against it.  The timeout could be a symptom of a bigger issue with the overall design of the database.

Comment: Most likely a bigger issue with the hardware. Unless the table is unusualle wide - 400.000 rows are comically low a size. That is unless this is a one disc system that overloads the IO. I have distincted 130 million record tables without problems in a minute or so - 400.000 is nothing for even a small but properly set up server.

Comment: DISTINCT is a form of aggregate... an index will help if it's not SELECT * and you can limit it to keys. Otherwise an index won't help if it has to over all columns = table scan anyway